# Drawable in string resource

Tags: android, string, drawable, android-resources

I want to show `AlertDialog` that shows its message with string and icons together.

Is it possible to insert icons/images/drawables in string resource? Is there any way to show drawables with the string in the `AlertDialog`.

**EDIT**
If its was not clear, the drawables need to be inside the string. like "click the icon [icon-image] and then click on..."

Comment: http://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/compound-drawables/

Comment: I meant in the middle of the string...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AlertDialog.Builder` class has a method `setIcon(int iconRes)` or `setIcon(Drawable icon)` that you can use for this.

EDIT:

If you need it in the middle of the string, you could use an `ImageSpan`:

```
String src = "Here's an icon: @ isn't it nice?";
SpannableString str = new SpannableString(src);
int index = str.indexOf("@");
str.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_icon), index, index + 1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE));

AlertDialog.Builder x = new AlertDialog.Builder(myContext);
x.setMessage(str);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it in the `string.xml` resource file?

Comment: You could abstract this into some custom TextView that checks a string for some format (e.g. `{{R.drawable.my_icon}}`) that resolves the drawable and parses it into a span automatically, but then you would also need to create a subclass of Dialog that would use this custom TextView, which is not a small amount of work.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that this tiny basic thing implemented already by android sdk.

Answer (score 12):

```
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("@");
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    spannableString.setSpan(span, spannableString.toString().indexOf("@"),  spannableString.toString().indexOf("@")+1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    yourTextView.setText(spannableString);
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Comment: @AkashBisariya Thanks a ton for this solution. You saved lot of effort of creating custom component

Comment: welcome @RajSuvariya and thanks to the Stackoverflow that provides us a great medium to help each other.

Comment: @AkashBisariya This is working fine in TextView but I want to use image inside the text in text input layout error. When I try to assign this spannableString to error state it is not showing the image. Instead, it is showing the "@" sign. Please help me if you know how to use this same technique for TextinputLayout error

Comment: @RajSuvariya have you find solution to your problem?

Comment: @RajSuvariya In text input layout?

Comment: have you find solution to text input layout problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! i had to made a few modiffications for my case and It worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView%28android.view.View%29) or [custom title](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29) with ImageView or TextView containing compound drawables.